# JavaScript for-loop: how to make my number translator work?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am trying to make a number translator, translating the number from one language to another. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. What is my fault? Or have I mistaken something? Thanks a lot!

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>LT3210 example: for loop</title>

<script>
function translate()
{
 var engNum = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"];
 var chiNum = ["零", "一", "二", "三", "四", "五", "六", "七", "八", "九", "十"];

 var myEngNum = document.getElementById("num_input").value;
 var trans = "";
 for (var i = 0; i < engNum.length; i++)
 { var curEngNum = engNum[i];
  while(myEngNum == curEngNum){
   trans = chiNum[i];
   document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = trans;
  }
 }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Number Translator</h1>
<form>
<input type="text" id="num_input" size="30" placeholder="Enter a number in English" />
</form>
<br />
<button onclick="translate()">Translate</button>
<br />
<p id="output">??</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can't use  `translate` as function name.

Secondly, you need to do an `if` statement in stead of `while` loop.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>LT3210 example: for loop</title>

<script>
function translate2()
{
 var engNum = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"];
 var chiNum = ["零", "一", "二", "三", "四", "五", "六", "七", "八", "九", "十"];

 var myEngNum = document.getElementById("num_input").value;
 var trans = "";
 for (var i = 0; i < engNum.length; i++)
 { 
      var curEngNum = engNum[i];
  if(myEngNum == curEngNum){
   trans = chiNum[i];
   document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = trans;
  }
 }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Number Translator</h1>
<form>
<input type="text" id="num_input" size="30" placeholder="Enter a number in English" />
</form>
<br />
<button onclick="translate2()">Translate</button>
<br />
<p id="output">??</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either, at least not when I test it on JSFiddle.

Comment: Possibly an issue with my browser then.

Comment: It can't be a browser issue, I think. It's only javascript. When you test the snippet, is it working?

Comment: Nope, nothing happens when clicking the button after entering a number. It doesn't work in the built-in "run code snippet" on this page either.

Comment: Weird, what is your console saying?

Comment: @JohnClifford you need input number like this "ten"

Comment: Doh. I'm not firing on any of the cylinders today, I was trying to use digits. Ignore me.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! I found that it's the problem of the wording 'translate', the code is actually working!;))

Answer (score 0):

First, `<button>` has a property named `translate`, so if you want to use the global function, you have to use `window.translate` for it to resolve correctly.

Second, you should use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` when dealing with non-HTML.

And third, you can dispose of both loops and make the translation a lot simpler by making use of [`Array.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and the `||` operator:

```
var myEngNum = document.getElementById("num_input").value;
var index = engNum.indexOf(myEngNum);
// If index == -1, chiNum[index] will evaluate to undefined, so we || it with '??'
var trans = chiNum[index] || '??';
document.getElementById("output").textContent = trans;
```

Or, as a one-liner:

```
document.getElementById("output").textContent = chiNum[engNum.indexOf(document.getElementById("num_input").value)] '??';
```

Your code fully fixed:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>LT3210 example: for loop</title>
    <script>
    function translate()
    {
        var engNum = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"];
        var chiNum = ["零", "一", "二", "三", "四", "五", "六", "七", "八", "九", "十"];
        document.getElementById("output").textContent = chiNum[engNum.indexOf(document.getElementById("num_input").value)] || '??';
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Number Translator</h1>
    <form>
    <input type="text" id="num_input" size="30" placeholder="Enter a number in English" />
    </form>
    <br />
    <button onclick="window.translate()">Translate</button>
    <br />
    <p id="output">??</p>
</body>
</html>
```